# Embedded files with Roslyn compilation

Tags: c#, roslyn, embedded-resource

I am looking for an example in how to compile a project using Roslyn. The code below is an example I found in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/FAQ … This examples doesn't cover embedded files. Is that possible?

```
public class MyTask : Task {
    public override bool Execute() {
          var projectFileName = this.BuildEngine.ProjectFileOfTaskNode;
              var project = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.
                            GetLoadedProjects(projectFileName).Single();
              var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                                    project.GetPropertyValue("AssemblyName"),
                                    syntaxTrees: project.GetItems("Compile").Select(
                                      c => SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit(
                                               c.EvaluatedInclude).SyntaxTree),
                                    references: project.GetItems("Reference")
                                                       .Select(          
                                      r => new MetadataFileReference
                                                   (r.EvaluatedInclude)));
             // Now work with compilation ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to embed resources into result assembly using Roslyn.

To produce a result assembly [CSharpCompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation) type has an `Emit` method. This method has many parameters. One of them is `manifestResources`, which is responsible for adding embedded resources. You mas specify as many resources as you want. The following code demonstrates how you can use this parameter to emit an assembly with an embedded resource into `peStream`. It creates a resource with name "resourceName" and content that located at "path-to-resource" path.

```
void ProduceAssembly(CSharpCompilation compilation, Stream peStream)
{
    ResourceDescription[] resources =
    {
        new ResourceDescription(
            "resourceName",
            () => File.OpenRead("path-to-resource"),
            isPublic: true
        )
    };
    var result = compilation.Emit(peStream, manifestResources: resources);
    if (!result.Success)
    {
        var diagnostics = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Diagnostics);
        throw new Exception($"Compilation failed with: {diagnostics}");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check `EmitResult.Success` property to ensure that compilation completed successfully. Also ensure that `peStream` is disposed properly after compilation.