# How to compile WPF's Resource Dictionary with CSharpCompilation programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, roslyn, resourcedictionary

I need to create **dll** containing ResourceDictionary for WPF (.net framework) application, from data from DB in environment running on .NET Core 3.1 runtime.

Let's say, I want to add this ResourceDictionary into dll:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="theKey">Value</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I tried to use [CSharpCompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation), but I'm struggling on how to 'compile xaml'. Tried to add it as resource ([using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961143/911929)), however it's not the same as when I compile it. Compiled resource dictionary is represented as ****.g.resources*** file in assembly's Manifest Resources.

Any idea whether this is even possible to do with [CSharpCompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation)?

Comment: You can use https://aka,ms/msbuildlog to see how the XAML is being converted to .NET resources.

Comment: XAML is not C#. You need MSBuild to *compile* the XAML. But why don't you just *parse* the markup using the `XamlReader` class?

Comment: @mm8 Because target application was designed to accept compiled Resource Dictionaries. But yes, finally I'm gonna use `XamlReader` on client side